# Variable in PHP http link

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the cureent url and send that through in a link and I'm stuck. The link displays but it's missing the url that I want to include (content in the code sample here)

```
'href' => ( "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&choe=UTF-8&chld=H&chl='.$content .'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes aren't correct:

```
'href' => ( "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&choe=UTF-8&chld=H&chl=".$content)
```

You should also use urlencode() and urldecode() to ensure the $content variable is properly  formatted

*Edit* 
Try this then:

```
$currentUrl = rawurlencode($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
$newUrl = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&choe=UTF-8&chld=H&chl=";

header("Location: $newUrl.$currentUrl");
```

//Not sure if path_info will always contain the full url but there are lots of functions on the web to grab the current url that you can google for.

Comment: Your original post looks like a fragment of an array.

should be $arr = array(
'href' => ( "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&choe=UTF-8&chld=H&chl=".rawurlencode($content))
);

Then you would access that variable as $arr['href']

so if you wanted to redirect to that url it would be 
header('Location: '.$arr['href']);

Comment: Thanks - your first solution was fine, I had the $content set in the wrong place. Thanks for your efforts. D

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing single and double quotes. Try this:

```
'href' => ( "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&choe=UTF-8&chld=H&chl=".rawurlencode($content))
```

Answer (score 3):

**First**: use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php):

```
$content = urlencode($content);
```

**Second**: replace your single quote with double quote.